# PHP echoing from within a nested while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking to echo values from two tables which are related on a HTML page. To do this I have queried the tables and set a while loop within a while loop to echo the output.

The database tables each have a column of a unique_id which is a foreign key in the next table. The first table is queried using the session email of the user to get that unique_id. The next table is then queried using that value.

The first set of data echo's fine but the next is blank.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Your Scorecards</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../assets/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
    <?php
    $connect =mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','micaddy');
    $id_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT unique_id FROM users WHERE email = '{$_SESSION['login_user']}'");
    $id_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id_query);
    $uid = $id_array['unique_id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM rounds WHERE user_id = '$uid'");

    $rnd_id_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT unique_id FROM rounds WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
    $rnd_id_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rnd_id_query);
    $round_id = $rnd_id_array['unique_id'];

    $hole = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM holes WHERE course_id = '$round_id'");


    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Your Rounds</strong></h3></div>
                <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong><?php echo $row['course_name'];?> &nbsp <?php echo $row['round_date']?> </strong></h3></div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                            <table style="width:100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Hole Number</th>
                                                    &nbsp
                                                    <th>Yards</th>
                                                    &nbsp
                                                    <th>Par</th>
                                                    &nbsp
                                                    <th>Shots</th>
                                                    <?php while($hole_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hole)): ?>
                                                    <?php if($hole_row['course_id'] === $row['unique_id']){ ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo $hole_row['hole_number']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $hole_row['yards']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $hole_row['par']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $hole_row['shots']; ?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <?php } ?>          
                                                    <?php endwhile; ?>  
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>                                        
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the current output:[image]

Comment: <?php if($hole_row['course_id'] === $row['unique_id']){ ?>  This is stopping the rest of the records from coming through. Try omitting it

Comment: same result I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your nested query inside your outer loop and since you are already setting `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rnd_id_query)` change to this:

```
$round_id = $row['unique_id'];
$hole = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM holes WHERE course_id = '$round_id'");
```

Comment: Perfect! Working like a charm. Will accept answer shortly.